# SetState of onPlacePicked to Text Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some idiot proof setState help... So I have a location picker (Google Maps) and I want the pickedlocation to be shown as a text in the place where you see 'Placeholder result'. Anyone has an idea how to approach this?

```dart
ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(EvaIcons.pinOutline),
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
                    title: Text('Placeholder result'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return PlacePicker(
                            apiKey: "API-KEY",
                            initialPosition: AddEventPage.kInitialPosition,
                            useCurrentLocation: true,
                            selectInitialPosition: true,
                            onPlacePicked: (result) {
                              setState(() {});
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          );
                        }),
                      );
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have a variable within the `State` of a `StatefulWidget`. I've used `ResultTile` as an example here:

```dart
class ResultTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResultTileState createState() => _ResultTileState();
}

class _ResultTileState extends State<ResultTile> {
  String _result = ''; // initially the result is an empty string

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(EvaIcons.pinOutline),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
      title: Text(_result), // display the result
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return PlacePicker(
              apiKey: "API-KEY",
              initialPosition: AddEventPage.kInitialPosition,
              useCurrentLocation: true,
              selectInitialPosition: true,
              onPlacePicked: (result) {
                setState(() {
                  _result = result
                      .getText(); // get the String from the result object, if it's not a String already.
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do have one more question regarding this if you have the time :) Do you know how I can have a placeholder like "Select a location" to be displayed before the location has been picked? Now it is of course an empty spot.

Comment: You can just set "Select a location" initially, it does not have to be an empty string. I just chose it as an example